# Firebase project - Functions folder in top folder

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to have the functions folder in the same level directory as `firebase.json`?

I am guessing it would be something like this:

```
{
    "functions": {
        "source": "**"
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.  By default, the functions folder is already sibling to firebase.json.  The name of the folder is given in the "source" property of the "functions" element.

Comment: @DougStevenson yes I don't want it to be a sibling. I want it to be parallel

Comment: To me, those words mean the same thing,  Maybe you could edit the question to illustrate more clearly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think OP wants to store their `index.js` in the top-level of their project, instead of in a `functions` folder under there.